# Jquery how to untrigger a function

Tags: jquery, function, triggers

I'm creating a dynamic form. I have a dropdown list which when the user makes a selection, the database is queried to see if the item required privacy or not. If it doesn't then additional fields are added to the form. Also a zip code lookup ajax function is triggered, but should only be triggered if the item is not private.

This is all working fine, until a user changes their mind...

Here is the relevant part of my code that runs when ever an item is selected from the dropdown;

```
success:function(response){
    if(response === '1'){
        // do stuff for item that requires privacy
        // do NOT trigger zip_check function
    }else if(response === '0'){
        // do stuff for item that is public +
        $('#zip-code').keyup(zip_check); // triggers a function to check zip code
    }
}
```

This works as expected until a user selects a non private item then changes their mind and selects a private item in which case the zip_check function will still run even though it now shouldn't be getting triggered. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: if possible please provide the html you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) (add this in the `(response===1){}`  ):

```
$('#zip-code').off('keyup', zip_check);
```

This way you remove that function from the click event. If you want all events removed, just use

```
$('#zip-code').off('keyup');
```

If you want all events off:

```
$('#zip-code').off();
```

`.off()` is the prefered method over [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/), and [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

try this:

for binding:

```
$('#zip-code').on('keyup',zip_check);
```

and for unbinding:

```
$('#zip-code').off('keyup',zip_check);
```