# How to remove on click from sorting table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

First time post although I've been following helpful advice from here for a while.

I've a table that is being sorted via some Jquery functions that I didn't build myself so not sure how it operates. If a header column is clicked it sorts the table by that column firtst up then down - standard stuff. I'd like to remove the sorting on the first column as this is a series of checkboxes and the sorting is interfering with the checkall function on a mobile.

I've tried using the following script. First to remove the sorting class, and then to try and remove the on click function. The class is being removed (so the javascript is working) but one can still click the header at which point a new class is assigned so this removeAttr isn't really working (which was the solution I'd found on this site).

```
<script>
!function ($) {   
    $(function(){   
        $('th:first-child').removeClass( "sorting" );   
        $('th:first-child').removeAttr('onclick');
    })
}(window.jQuery)
</script>
```

Any help gratefully received. Many thanks, DomC

Comment: How is the click event registered?

Comment: don't try to undo what the other code that you don't understand does... go to the other code and fix it at the source.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery how to untrigger a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223167/jquery-how-to-untrigger-a-function)

Comment: @KevinB There may be a case where either he is not allowed to or doesn't have skills/time to modify the source of that table sorter code. Is it really harmful to do such a small monkey patch?

Comment: maintenance-wise, yes it can be very harmful. a monkey patch like that could cost another developer that doesn't know about it many hours of work time trying to figure out why his sort isn't working.

Comment: true. But if the monkey patch is localized using a wrapper to a specific table on which the sorter is applied and clearly mentioned in the comments? will that be okay?

Comment: I'm not sure how the click event is registered, as to be honest I'm pretty new to javascript/jquery. I've tried digging around Firebug's Dom panel to try and look at this stuff but the documentation / tutorials that I found on how to use it aren't easy for newbie to follow.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the `.removeAttr('onclick')` doesnt work is because there is a global eventhandler, probably in some .js file (which is the proper place!). The onclick would be inline javascript, which is a no-no!

To get it out of the global eventhandler list, use jQuery's [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
// this removes all functions bound on the 'click event
$('th:first-child').off('click');
```

Or, if you have an older version of jQuery, [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

```
// this removes all functions bound on the 'click event (older jQuery example)
$('th:first-child').unbind('click');
```

Or, if you want only one function turned off:

```
// If ´otherFunction´ is bound to click aswell, it will remain working
$('th:first-child').off('click', functionname);
```

Or, remove ALL events (ie click, hover, resize):

```
// Or the big cleanup, this clears ALL functions from ALL events
$('th:first-child').off();
```

Comment: Can you explain more about removeAttr('onclick') and global eventhandler. at which time onclick="something" is parsed and why removing it wont work.

Comment: Thank you Martijn (and everyone else) for your speedy responses to this. The first one works. There's a strange quirk in that when you select one of the other headers to sort that column then some javascript somewhere applies back the class which I'd removed. Is there a feature like the .off that I can apply that will stop the class being reintroduced when you sort another column.

Comment: Please mark the answer as solution if you think it is :) To answer your other question: I think you should look for whats doing it and fix that. Its better to fix the problem than to hide it

Answer (score 0):

@**Martijn** answer will probably do what you want. But i am putting more details here.

It depends on how the events (`click`) are registered.
removing the class or onclick attribute from the first header cell may not help.

They may have been used for binding the onclick event to that element. But You need to unbind the event.

When a user clicks on the header cell, it triggers an event. There are methods binded to the events which gets executed on the trigger. There may be one or multiple such methods which gets executed on the event.

In this case the event is `click`.

To remove bindings for all the methods for `click`, you can use following -

```
$('th:first-child').off('click');

//For old Jquery Version as mentioned by @Matijn
//$('th:first-child').unbind('click');
```

If you wish to unbind a specific method -

```
$('th:first-child').off('click', reference_to_function);
```

Comment: I believe I have the same info about only removing 1 function or event, I'll clearify it a bit more :)

Comment: I was initially editing your answer. Cause i think OP doesnt know about the events in the first place.